# Specify route for integrated/embedded NativeScript from Java

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

***How do I choose what gets displayed when I start a NativeScript view from an Android app?***

I have an Android app with a few Activities written in Java and I have embedded a NativeScript app with several views within the Java app. I can start the NativeScript app from one my Activities written in Java, but it always starts with the default route.

A complete example is the so-40870998 branch of [this GitHub project](https://github.com/ross-bradbury/ns-embed-example/tree/so-40870998).

I have successfully followed the instructions to [extend your existing Android app with Angular 2 and NativeScript](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/integration-with-existing-ios-and-android-apps/extend-existing-android-app-with-ns-angular2) but I have not figured out how to specify the current route (or any other way to specify what view shows up initially) in the NativeScript part of my app from the Java part of my app.

---

My NativeScript app is using Angular2, TypeScript and has some routes just like the sample groceries app.

In my Java activity I have these methods:

```
private void showSpinner() {
    // TODO: This would need to be improved. It just shows something happened when the buttons are tapped.
    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void showScreen1(View view) {
    showSpinner();

    // TODO: Go to /welcome (currently going to "/" and being redirected)
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            show(MyCustomNativeScriptActivity.class);
        }
    }, 500);
}


public void showScreen2(View view) {
    showSpinner();

    // TODO: Go to /demo
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            show(MyCustomNativeScriptActivity.class);
        }
    }, 500);
}

private <T> void show(Class<T> clazz) {
    com.tns.Runtime runtime = com.tns.RuntimeHelper.initRuntime(getApplication());
    if (runtime != null) {
        runtime.run();

        android.content.Intent intent = new android.content.Intent(MainActivity.this, clazz);
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I am using MyCustomNativeScriptActivity.js and MyCustomNativeScriptFragment.js from
https://github.com/enchev/android-ng2-tns/tree/master/app/src/main/assets/app

I am using MyCustomNativeScriptActivity.java and MyCustomNativeScriptFragment.java from https://github.com/enchev/android-ng2-tns/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/myexistingapplication

---

I have tried navigating in the JS file for the activity from onStart and from onResume like this:

MyCustomNativeScriptActivity.js:

```
var frame = require("ui/frame");
require("./MyCustomNativeScriptFragment");
var MyCustomNativeScriptActivity = (function (_super) {

...

MyCustomNativeScriptActivity.prototype.onStart = function () {
    this._callbacks.onStart(this, _super.prototype.onStart);
    frame_1.topmost().navigate("/demo");
};

...

    return MyCustomNativeScriptActivity;
}(android.app.Activity));
```

Trying to navigate in onResume doesn't do anything.

Trying to navigate in onStart results in this error:

```
12-15 14:06:23.024 7297-7297/? W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myexistingapplication/com.example.myexistingapplication.MyCustomNativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
12-15 14:06:23.024 7297-7297/? W/System.err: Calling js method onStart failed
12-15 14:06:23.024 7297-7297/? W/System.err: Error: Failed to load Page from entry.moduleName: /demo
12-15 14:06:23.024 7297-7297/? W/System.err: File: "/data/data/com.example.myexistingapplication/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js, line: 92, column: 12
12-15 14:06:23.024 7297-7297/? W/System.err: StackTrace: 
12-15 14:06:23.024 7297-7297/? W/System.err:    Frame: function:'resolvePageFromEntry', file:'/data/data/com.example.myexistingapplication/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 92, column: 19
12-15 14:06:23.025 7297-7297/? W/System.err:    Frame: function:'Frame.navigate', file:'/data/data/com.example.myexistingapplication/files/app/tns_modules/ui/frame/frame-common.js', line: 165, column: 20
12-15 14:06:23.025 7297-7297/? W/System.err:    Frame: function:'MyCustomNativeScriptActivity.onStart', file:'/data/data/com.example.myexistingapplication/files/app/MyCustomNativeScriptActivity.js', line: 21, column: 27
12-15 14:06:23.025 7297-7297/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
12-15 14:06:23.025 7297-7297/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
12-15 14:06:23.026 7297-7297/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
12-15 14:06:23.026 7297-7297/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
12-15 14:06:23.026 7297-7297/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-15 14:06:23.026 7297-7297/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
12-15 14:06:23.026 7297-7297/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
12-15 14:06:23.026 7297-7297/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-15 14:06:23.026 7297-7297/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
12-15 14:06:23.026 7297-7297/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Did you try setting MyCustomNativeScriptActivity (with the full class name) in the activity -> LAUNCH entry in your manifest?

Comment: @pkanev Thanks. The app "works" fine. I can start the activity and that starts the NativeScript part. The thing is I want two different buttons on a native Java Activity to launch different NativeScript pages. That is what I cannot figure out - it starts the NativeScript app at the default (empty string) route.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this issue @RossBradbury?  We are in the early stages of attempting to do this for iOS and Android where we have a existing app and want to navigate to certain sections from the main app?

Comment: @Zuriel no, I never figured it out, but I didn't work on it much after the original post. I had considered using some form of local storage to store a starting route to navigate to, and setting that during the button handler that launched the nativescript portion.